# ColorPicker on sheet taps outside

Tags: ipad, swiftui, color-picker, dismiss

I have a problem with SwiftUI and the ColorPicker, only for iPad. On iPhone and Mac it works fine.

When I use a ColorPicker inside a sheet, I open the picker to choose the color and I click (without closing the picker) the button to close the sheet, the button is clicked, but the dismiss() is done on the picker and not on the sheet.

The problem is that once the picker is closed, the dismiss stops working on the sheet and I can't close it with the button, but by clicking outside of it.

I attach the code of the example, simplified to the maximum. The behavior in my app is exactly the same.

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct Pruebas: View {
    
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button("Show") {
            showSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Detail()
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct Detail: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State private var color: Color = .orange
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ColorPicker("Color", selection: $color)
                    .padding()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Color")
            
            .toolbar {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Xcode 14.2, iOS 16.2. Show the picker, tap outside the picker and it is dismissed, then tap the Cancel button to dismiss the sheet all works as expected. (You should remove `.foregroundColor(.white)` as the Cancel button can't be seen)

Comment: No, the problem is when you tap outside the picker but directly at the cancel button.
1. Show the picker.
2. With the picker opened, click directly at the Cancel button. (it dismiss the picker and makes a tap on the button, but does'nt dismiss the sheet.
3. Even though you click on the cancel button it does nothing. The sheet does'nt dismiss. Only does if you tap outside the sheet.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm doing. I click where the Cancel button is, but it doesn't actually click the button, the Picker is dismissed because I'm clicking outside of it. Putting a breakpoint on `dismiss()` it's only called when the button is clicked after the sheet is dismissed.

Comment: Did you try on iPad? On iPhone and Mac works well, because the picker is different (iPhone has a button to close and Mac keeps opened). Did you try at simulator or real device?

Comment: You're right! Sorry, that was my mistake, I didn't read your question properly. I missed that it was for iPad

Comment: Don't worry i just found it weird that it worked different from my experience

Comment: Could you try passing in `$showSheet` as a Binding? `.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { Detail(showSheet: $showSheet) }` ... `struct Detail: View { @Binding var showSheet: Bool }` .. then replace `dismiss()` with `showSheet = false`